# Performant filling of NAs with grouping

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am looking for a solution regarding a problem with a very big dataframe in pandas.

Let's say I have a very big dataframe that has NAs in it. I want to fill the NAs by the mean of the rows with the same ID. I know that some IDs are not relevant for me (see the array "ids" in the sample code).

I came up with the following code:

```
# relevant Ids
ids = [2,3]
# create example dataframe
test = pd.DataFrame([[1,1,4],[1,np.nan,np.nan],[1,3,5],[2,np.nan,3],[2,5,5],[2,7,np.nan],[3,4,np.nan],[3,np.nan,3],[3,8,9]],columns=['id','v1','v2'])
# fill NAs with the mean of the group defined by ID
test[test.id.isin(ids)] = pd.concat([test[test.id.isin(ids)].id,test[test.id.isin(ids)].groupby('id').transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))],axis=1)
```

I am using this in an environment where there is a loop around that. 
In every loop around 1000 rows will be added to the dataframe and I have to fill the NAs for these rows.

This means, that every little bit of performance I can get out of this would be awesome. I tried to avoid creating copies of the dataframe since that seems to be even slower.

Maybe someone has an idea? I think that for example filtering with isin() three times should be avoided but I couldn't find a solution without copying the dataframe.

I am no expert in python or pandas so there might be something I missed.

Comment: Typically how many columns do you have?

Comment: Actually i would be happy with a solution for 2 columns: ID and value for example

Comment: And if there are more than one row with NaN, we would fill in the same average value into all those rows?

Comment: Every row has an ID. But the value could be missing. If that is the case, fill the value with the average of all rows with the same ID

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you?

Comment: Hi. Yes your solution is working most of the time. I had an error however. I am currently looking for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a NumPy solution that iterates through the columns -

```
a = test.values
ID = a[:,0].astype(int)
for i in range(1,test.shape[1]):
    nan_mask = np.isnan(a[:,i])
    ids_i = np.intersect1d(ID[~nan_mask], ids) # Account for at least 1 NaN grp
    valid_mask = np.in1d(ID, ids_i)
    m1 = ~nan_mask & valid_mask
    m2 = nan_mask & valid_mask
    s1 = np.bincount(ID[m1],a[m1,i])/np.bincount(ID[m1])
    test.iloc[m2,i] = s1[ID[m2],None]
```

Comment: This solution works very well. However: do you have an idea how to account for ID where every value is nan? This leads to an error for me. I want to ignore these rows. 

I think it would be enough to remove the ID from array m2 if it does not appear in m1.

Comment: @hhllcks Check out the edits, most probably a better one.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are doing a lot of work. Couldn't you just replace all the missing values first and then filter

```
test[['v1', 'v2']] = test.groupby('id').transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
test[test.id.isin(ids)]
```

And one more way without transform

```
test.set_index('id') \
    .fillna(test.groupby('id').mean()) \
    .loc[ids] \
    .reset_index()
```